# Preg_match apache log to PHP array

Tags: php, regex, apache, preg-match

I want to get my apache's logs in PHP array to put them in the database, I tried this code :

```
$log = file_get_contents("path/to/my/apache/access_log");
$regex = '/^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([^:]+):(\d+:\d+:\d+) ([^\]]+)\] \"(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)\" (\S+) (\S+) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"$/';
preg_match($regex, $log, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

It didn't work, the array is empty but i don't know why.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: so break down the regex into smaller parts and figure out which part(s) are NOT doing their job properly. that's something YOU have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to match the line with

```
/^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([^:]+):(\d+:\d+:\d+) ([^\]]+)\] \"(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)\" (\S+) (\S+)/gm
```

Note the m (multiline) ang g (global) flags at the end. You may also need to use `preg_match_all` function or yet better process the file one line at a time.